# Entity Framework Linq embed lambda expressions into a reusable function

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda, linq-to-entities

When using Linq with Entity Framework to query the database, is there a way of reducing repetitive lambdas? For example:

```
db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == "MM001" && x.Type == 1 && x.IsActive == True && x.ExpiryDate > DateTime.Now);
```

I would like to turn it into just:

```
db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == "MM001" && x.IsActiveStaff());
```

I have tried writing a method as follow into my Users POCO:

```
public bool IsActiveStaff()
{
    return Type == 1 && IsActive == True && ExpiryDate > DateTime.Now;
}
```

However, I get the following error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsActiveStaff()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I realise this is because LINQ To Entities cannot turn this method into an SQL Expression, but is there any way I can get this to work?

I know that I can write a query command class which simply takes a Username as a parameter, and place all of my logic in there, but I'd like to know if you can embed a series of lambdas into a method or extension method etc, and use them when required like in my example above.

Comment: For re-using select lambdas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38766411/how-to-parameterize-a-selector-with-a-function-in-ef-query (This question has a higher SEO)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an expression of the appropriate type:

```
Expression<Func<User, bool>> IsActiveStaff = x => x.Type == 1 && x.IsActive && x.ExpiryDate > DateTime.Now;
```

Then:

```
db.Users.Where(IsActiveStaff).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == "MM001");
```

Comment: @JeffDunlop it doesn't even compile, as I was thinking of delegates rather than expressions. It is possible to compose predicates into other predicates with expressions, but it's more convoluted than is worth in this case. I'd edited to remove that bit.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer using extension methods like:

```
public static class UsersExtensions
{
  public static IQueryable<User> IsActive(this IQueryable<User> u)
  {
    // Should really use UTC
    return u.Where(x=>x.IsActive && x.ExpiryDate>DateTime.Now);
  }
  public static IQueryable<User> IsStaff(this IQueryable<User> u)
  {
    return u.Where(x=>x.Type==1);
  }
}
```

Used like (with full intellisense):

```
var result=db.Users
  .IsActive()
  .IsStaff()
  .FirstOrDefault(x=>x.UserName=="MM001");
```

Comment: I didn't think of doing it this way. I have marked the other answer as correct since it most closely answers my question, but I prefer this syntax.

Comment: To be fair, I liked his answer too.  Short, sweet, and did exactly what you asked.  I just offered an alternative.

Comment: Both approaches have their place, depending on just how you're likely to re-use the filter only as a `Where` or re-use the predicate in other ways.